# Bootstrap for IE8 and below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have developed a dynamic site using PHP Codeigniter. I have used bootstrap V3.2.0 framework for the website to be responsive. Now, the issue is, the entire website's alignment is different in IE8 and the other below versions. The look and feel of the website has been completely changed in IE8, Kindly suggest me on fixing this issue.

Comment: You need to include Respond.js on your page to get the media queries to work properly.. >> http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have tried adding this but it was not helpful :(, will there be a conflict between botsrap files with codeigniter ?

Comment: Are you testing this off a server? because IE8 has a security issue associated with it and bootstrap, however once on a server the issue resolves. This site helped me resolve this same issue for a website I created > http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9

Comment: Yes, I am testing this on server. I am facing the same issue in local as well. We have referred your BLog and used the code which was mentioned, still the issue persists. :(

Comment: I assume that there are no other JS errors,, so it must be that security issue as stated:" Due to browser security rules, Respond.js doesn't work with pages viewed via the file:// protocol (like when opening a local HTML file). To test responsive features in IE8, view your pages over HTTP(S). See the Respond.js docs for details." - https://www.drupal.org/node/2173441 I'm afraid that without seeing more of your source, i'm unable to assist further. :( - Hope I was of some assistance though. PS when i said on a server i meant using an address like : localhost:8080/blahaha/index.html etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this code into head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can check supported tags, functions in any browser, with web site http://caniuse.com/. IE8 and below doesn't support html5 and CSS3.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, we have tried adding this to the site but it was not helpful :(, the issue still persists.